# Canvas object literal: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of undefined

Tags: javascript, canvas

Why does using an object literal, as below, produce this error?

```
<canvas id="game" width="568" height="320"></canvas>


var GAME = {
    settings: {
        canvas: document.getElementById('game'),
        context: this.canvas.getContext('2d'),
        gameWidth: this.context.width,
        gameHeight: this.context.height
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `this` is the global context, that is `window`. You can't refer in the properties of an object literal to the object itself.

A solution :

```
var GAME = {
    settings: {
        canvas: document.getElementById('game');
    }
};
GAME.settings.context = GAME.settings.canvas.getContext('2d');
GAME.settings.gameWidth = GAME.settings.context.width;
GAME.settings.gameHeight = GAME.settings.context.height;
```

You may use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) for a cleaner code :

```
var GAME = (function(){
   var s = {};
   s.canvas = document.getElementById('game');
   s.context = s.canvas.getContext('2d');
   s.gameWidth = s.context.width;
   s.gameHeight = s.context.height;
   return { settings : s}
})();
```